# Помогите с регулярным выражением Java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Помогите реализовать регулярное выражение, которое будет выделять слова, в которых первые три буквы согласные. Не могу никак подобрать грамотное выражение.

Вот код всего проекта.

```
package ua.lviv.iot;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class WordReplacer {

    public static String replaceWrongWords(String text, String changeStr) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b\b[^aeyuioAEYUIO 1-9]{3}\\b",
                Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        text = matcher.replaceAll(changeStr);
        return text;
    }
}
```

```
package ua.lviv.iot;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.junit.Test;

public class WordReplacerTest {

    @Test
    public void replaceWrongWordsTest() {
        String text = "throw word test";
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(text.getBytes());
        System.setIn(in);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        text = scanner.nextLine();
        scanner.close();
        String expected = "WRONG word test";
        String actual = WordReplacer.replaceWrongWords(text, "WRONG");
        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

Comment: Покажите пример ваших регулярок, чтобы нам стало понятно, что вы пытались.

Comment: \b[^aeyuioAEYUIO 1-9]{3}

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/MOt52f/1

Comment: Может выглядеть примерно так: [aeyuio]{3}\w*

Comment: @StateItPrimitive не сработало.

Comment: @StateItPrimitive попробуйте 1eee или zzzeee, думаю нужно добавить \b в начало

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/MOt52f/2

Comment: Получилось, благодарю.

Comment: @StateItPrimitive а почему не \b? какой кейс он не покрывает?

Comment: @IR42, да вы правы, \b будет лучшим вариантом, просто накидал то, что первое в голову пришло :)

Comment: Я еще регистрочувствительность выключил и слиял с предложением @IR42, вот по идее [конечный вариант](https://regex101.com/r/MOt52f/3)

Answer (score 1):

Рабочий вариант регулярного выражения может выглядеть [следующим образом](https://regex101.com/r/MOt52f/7):

`(?i)\b[BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ]{3}\w*`

Пример использования в рамках Java кода:

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?i)(\\b[BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ]{3}\\w*)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("abc bcd fghSome some pRqAbC XYZabc ZYabc");
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

*Примечание: оставил явный ответ, чтобы людям не приходилось копаться в комментариях к вопросу.*

Comment: Только `aeiou` - это не согласные...

Comment: @Qwertiy, хм, честно говоря, я теперь совсем запутался: в формулировке вопроса, и правда, явно сказано про согласные, но когда я попросил автора вопроса привести пример, подкрепляющий его попытки самостоятельного выполнения задачи, а также в ходе его ответов на комментарии у меня сложилось явное впечатление, что автор имел в виду именно гласные.

Comment: @Qwertiy, пересмотрел еще раз, все же, я ошибся, т.к. автор в комментарии поставил знак отрицания перед множеством значений `[^...]`. Либо он отредактировал комментарий, либо я был невнимателен :(

Comment: Хм.. Только сейчас заметил крышку в его ответе... `[^aeiou]` - это тоже не согласные - тут же всякий мусор проходить будет.

Comment: @Qwertiy, угу, понимаю, что туда попадет еще и всякий мусор, но это уже дает понять, что автор пытался отсечь гласные и логика становится ясна, но я умудрился упустить этот символ. Актуализировал ответ, чтобы не вводить никого в заблуждения еще больше :)

Comment: Да, вроде теперь логично смотрится.

Answer (score 0):

Вот рабочий вариант: \b[^aeyuioAEYUIO ]{3}\w*

Comment: 1. Что внутри делает пробел? 2. Согласные буквы от гласных кто отличать должен?

Comment: Я профан, и это лучшее что я смог сделать.

Comment: @Tobi, просто коллега подсказывает, что регулярка с пробелом не выполняет свою функцию

Comment: Тогда подскажите, как мне исключить пробел из предложения. Чтобы пробел не считало за символ.

Comment: @Tobi, https://regex101.com/r/MOt52f/3

Comment: @Tobi, я только сейчас осознал (за счет комментария к моему ответу), что вы пытаетесь выделять слова именно с согласными, а не гласными вначале, поэтому все мои более ранние предложения вам не подойдут, т.к. они, наоборот, ищут слова с тремя гласными вначале, [вот так](https://regex101.com/r/MOt52f/7) может выглядеть вариант с согласными.

В вашем же варианте логика ясна, но отсекая все подряд гласные и пробелы вы допускаете ряд других логически некорретных для вас слов (например, начинающихся с цифр).